# vino-server: share third display

Tags: multiple-monitors, vnc, vino

I want to share my third monitor (preferably via VNC) with another computer.

Is it possible to share just ONE display with vino? Because it defaults to sharing every monitor at once. I tried this command:

```
/urs/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0.2
```

But it did not work:

```
Cannot open display
```

Is there another way with vino or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I did not use x11vnc because 1/3 of my display was black, but i found the cause of this problem:
x11vnc defaults to using xinerama to black-out the non-screen-area, but it detected my displays wrong.
Disabling it with `-noxinerama` fixed it for me.

`x11vnc -clip 1368x768+439+0 -noxinerama` worked.

(You can get the numbers ⇧ by typing `xrandr --current`)